# How to separate two swiper instance hooks on the same page?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have two React Swipers on the same page.

I'm using `useSwiper` to create my own navigation buttons.

It works great for one swiper. But now that I have two instances on the same page, when I click the next on one instance, both of them go to the next item.

In other words, their navigations are tied together.

These swiper instances are inside two separate components.

```
const Home = () => {
    return <div>
       <FirstSection /> // This has a `useSwiper` in it
       <SecondSection /> // This also has a `useSwiper` in it
    </div>
}
```

How can I make these instances separate from each other?

I have searched the docs and I can't find what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a controller for each one take a look to the docs https://swiperjs.com/react#controller and check the example below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

const App = () => {
  // store swiper instances
  const [firstSwiper, setFirstSwiper] = useState(null);
  const [secondSwiper, setSecondSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <main>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        onSwiper={setFirstSwiper}
        controller={{ control: secondSwiper }}
      >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        onSwiper={setSecondSwiper}
        controller={{ control: firstSwiper }}
      >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  );
};
```